# Angular call controller method from directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I create simple project with angular and I use directive to create a simple grid like this code :

my directive :

```
app.directive('dpGrid',()=>{
    return{
        restrict:"E",
        scope:{
            items:"="
        }
        templateUrl: 'template/dbgrid.directive.html'
    }

});
```

my controller :

```
   app.controller('mainCtrl',($scope)=>{

$scope.data=[{fname:"david",lname:"orman",age:24,id:"234"}];

        $scope.update=(id)=>{
          console.log("ID :",id);
        };

    });
```

my directive template :

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>fname</th>
        <th>lname</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>opt</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items" >
        <th>{{$index}}</th>
        <td>{{item.fname}}</td>
        <td>{{item.lname}}</td>
        <td>{{item.age}}</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="update(item.id)">update</a></td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and I use directive like this :

```
<dp-grid items="data" ></dp-grid>
```

I want call `update()` method from directive template, but dont call update() method  when click on update btn

Comment: What is the question though?

Comment: if its in the template, it will have access to the scope method.   Just try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to specify the controller your directive should use, then access it in template.

```
return {
    restrict:"E",
    scope:{
        items:"="
    },
    controller: 'mainCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'template/dbgrid.directive.html'
}
```

Then you will be able to access the function in the templates. If you are accessing it from a child isolate scope, you may need to access it using $parent.